# Python for loop: index out of range error

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing, range

I'm trying to create a loop that will take what the user entered and print it back alternating between upper and lowercase.  Ex: the user enters 'helloworld', it prints back 'HeLlOwOrLd'.  Here's what I have so far (trust me, I know it's not optimal, it's just what I could get to work):

```
s = input("enter characters: ")
word = ''
count = 0


for i in s:
        up = s[::2]
        up2 = up.upper()
        up3 = up2[0 + count]
        low = s[1::2]
        low2 = low.lower()
        low3 = low2[0 + count]
        word += up3 + low3
        count += 1

print(word)
```

When I trace it in the debugger, word comes to the right value, and then it runs the loop again, thus getting the index out of range error.  Ideas?

Comment: The two most common problems in programming are cache validation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looping through too many times. Your splitting s in half in the loop, but looping once for each character in s.

```
s = input("enter characters: ")
word = ''


for count in range(len(s[::2])):
        up = s[::2]
        up2 = up.upper()
        up3 = up2[0 + count]
        low = s[1::2]
        low2 = low.lower()
        if(len(low2)>count):
            low3 = low2[0 + count]
        else:
            low3=''
        word += up3 + low3
        count += 1

print(word)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Why convert the entire string on each iteration, why do `0 + count` and why increment count?

Comment: The question asked for help regarding the error. The attempt was to change as little as possible to aide in seeing what caused the error.

Answer (score 2):

`count` will end up equal to the length of `s`. However, you are using `count` as an index for strings that are shorter than `s`, such as `up3`.

Try the following:

```
>>> result = ''
>>> word = 'hello'
>>> for i in range(len(word)):
...     result += (word[i].lower() if i%2 else word[i].upper())
...
>>> result
'HeLlO'
```

Also:

```
>>> word = 'HellOWorLD'
>>> ''.join(word[i].lower() if i%2 else word[i].upper() for i in range(len(word)))
'HeLlOwOrLd'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the case conversion functions from `string` and `itertools.cycle` to vary which one is applied to each character. Wrap that all up in a join statement and you get:

```
''.join(case(c) for case,c in 
    zip(itertools.cycle((string.upper,string.lower)), 'helloworld'))
```